# Работа с data-* атрибутами с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery, php

Вот есть такой span, который генерируется с помощью PHP:

```
<span data-price=\"$price\">$price грн.</span>
```

Как мне с помощью jQuery вытащить значение(число) из атрибута data-price?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('span').data('price');
```

В крайнем случае

```
$('span').attr('data-price');
```

Comment: У меня в обеих случаях выдает undefined ((

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MpNhr/

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо, второй вариант заработал!