# JS Как передавать значение из кнопки в input type=text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как передать значение из кнопки button в input type=text, но с помощью своего data атрибута, а не через value
До пустим есть мой data-myvalue=a при нажатие на кнопку button - значение переходит в inputy type=text

Мой пример передает значение из value а не из другого атрибута

```js
$('button.but').on('click', function() {
    $('#my_field3').val( $(this).val() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="but" value="a">A</button>
<button class="but" value="b">B</button>
<button class="but" value="c">C</button>

<input type="text" id="my_field3" value="">
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа с data-\* атрибутами с помощью jQuery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/230864/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-data-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery API Documentation `.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```js
$('button.but').on('click', function() {
  $('#my_field3').val($(this).data('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="but" data-value="a">A</button>
<button class="but" data-value="b">B</button>
<button class="but" data-value="c">C</button>

<input type="text" id="my_field3" value="">
```