# JS как из select получить значит и value и data-myval

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как из одного `select` получать значения `value` в поле `input type=text` и с этого же `select`'a получать значение в `span` из `data-myval`?

Вот мой код:

```js
$('select.but').on('click', function() {
    $('#my_field4').val( $(this).val() );
    $('.my_field4_span').text( $(this).val() );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" style="padding-top:20px">
<select class="but">
  <option data-myval="a2" value="a1">a</option>
  <option data-myval="b2" value="b1">b</option>
  <option data-myval="c2" value="c1">c</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="my_field4" value="">
<span class="my_field4_span"> </span>
</div>
```

Так же код в редакторе:
https://jsfiddle.net/synapse3/w0kr82a7/14/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа с data-\* атрибутами с помощью jQuery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/230864/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-data-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('select.but').on('change', function() {
  $('#my_field4').val($(this).val());
  $('.my_field4_span').text($(this).find('option:selected').data('myval'));
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" style="padding-top:20px">
  <select class="but">
    <option data-myval="a2" value="a1">a</option>
    <option data-myval="b2" value="b1">b</option>
    <option data-myval="c2" value="c1">c</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" id="my_field4" value="">
  <span class="my_field4_span"> </span>
</div>
```